# new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream, true)))

Tags: java, sockets, file-io, printwriter, bufferedwriter

I am wondering is it possible to do

```
new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream, true)))
```

in Java where s is a Socket? Because it's impossible to create a BufferedWriter from an outputstream, I have wrapped the outputstream with a PrintWriter. But I want to buffer my print outs, so I wrap it with a BufferedWriter. But eventually I want to print using printWriter so I wrap it again with a PrintWriter. Is this legal in Java? Thanks!

Comment: Also, if this is possible, what would be its behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is legal but clumsy. You can buffer `OutputStream` instead:

```
new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream), true)
```

Also have a look at the implementation of `new PrintWriter(OutputStream, boolean)`:

```
public PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush) {
  this(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out)), autoFlush);
}
```

buffering is already there!

Answer (score 1):

`OutputStreamWriter` is the class you're looking for.  Just pass it a stream and an encoding, for example `"UTF-8"`.

```
new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(), encoding)), true)
```